# Passing several arguments from an array to a function in a easy way

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, arguments

Well I really don't know how to describe this in words but I've an easy example:

```
def foo(x,y,z):
     r=x+....

a = [1,2,3]
foo(a[0], a[1], a[2])
```

Can I do the same without calling `a[n]` several times? but keeping "x,y,z" definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)!

```
>>> def foo(x,y,z):
...     return x+y+z
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> foo(*a)
6
```

From the documentation

> If they are not available separately, write the function call with the
>   *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple:
>
> ```
> >>> args = [3, 6]
> >>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list [3, 4, 5]
> ```

Comment: @Pablo Yep. See the docs. What are you trying? You cannot pass any other un-named arguments after that.

Comment: i found the answer on internet (that's why a deleted my comment), i'm doing some opengl stuff and well arguments are infinite ;/ so i'm doing my own functions, some take 9 arguments (from 3 different vectors), so i want to do "myRotate(*vectora, *vectorb, *vectorc, angle)

Comment: @Pablo Oops. Then you will need to add all of them to a single tuple or else you will have to create a feeder function

Comment: this might be a dumb question but is this faster and more python kosher then to say pass the list as a function argument such as foo(a) where a = [1,2,3]

Comment: @IntrepidTraveller Yep. That is the best way actually. However I haven't seen the internals of this. Once I see that I will get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah use unpacking operator to pass any arbitrary arguments to your function :

```
def foo(*args):
     for i in args : # you can iterate over args or get its elements by indexing
         #do stuff

a = [1,2,3]
foo(*a)
```

And if you just pass 3 argument you can use unpacking in call time.

```
def foo(x,y,z):
     r=x+....

a = [1,2,3]
foo(*a)
```

Comment: Damn we have answered at the same instant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
def foo(x,y,z):
     r=x+....

a = [1,2,3]
foo(*a)
```